# Dojo JsonRest store vs dojo.xhrGet

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx

I have seen examples of using dojo/request wrapper around dojo.xhrGet: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/populating_datagrid/  and JsonRest object store: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#dojo-store-jsonrest to populate datagrid.

Can anyone tell me what are the pros and cons of using one over the other?  I would like to use Gridx tree grid example and wondered which one would be best and why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `dojo/store/JsonRest` store will also allow you to create/update/delete items in your store which will be updated on your service as well. The only thing to know is that you have to follow certain guidelines when creating your service, which is explained at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#implementing-a-rest-server).

With `dojo/request/xhr` (AMD version of `dojo.xhr`), you can request information (such as the data from a REST service), but you will have to manually add it to a store which you could use in your grid.

So if your plan is to create/update/delete data as well, then `dojo/store/JsonRest` is probably the best choice. If it isn't, then you can still pick the `dojo/store/JsonRest` store if the webservice is conform or `dojo/request/xhr` when it isn't.

Comment: Thanks very much!  since, it is mostly for viewing, I will use the dojo/request/xhr.